# Characters not displayed correctly when reading CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv, character-encoding

I have an issue when trying to read a string from a .CSV file. When I execute the application and the text is shown in a textbox, certain characters such as "é" or "ó" are shown as a question mark symbol.
The idea is that this code reads the whole CSV file and then splits each line into variables depending on the first word of the line.

The code I'm using to read is:

```
Dim test() As String
test = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Libro1.csv")
Dim test_chart As String = Array.Find(vls1load, Function(x) (x.StartsWith("sample")))
Dim test_chart_div() As String = test_chart.Split(";")
variable1 = test_chart_div(1)
variable2 = test_chart_div(2)
...etc
```

I have also tried with:

```
Dim test() As String
test = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Libro1.csv", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

But none of them works. The .csv file is supposed to be UTF8. The "web options" that you can see when saving the file in excel show encoding UTF8. I also tried the trick of changing the file extension to HTML and opening it with the browser to see that the encoding is also correct.

Can someone advice anything else I can try?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't include tags in titles. That's what tags are for.

Comment: Do you get parsing errors when using UTF8?

Comment: @Danny_ds, no I did not get parsing errors with any of the two codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Excel file is exported using the **`CSV Comma Separated`** output format, the Encoding selected in **Tools -> Web Option -> Encoding** of Excel's **`Save As...`** dialog doesn't actually generate the expected result:
the Text file is saved using the Encoding relative to the current Language selected in the Excel Application, not the Unicode (UTF16-LE) or UTF-8 Encoding selected (which is ignored) nor the default Encoding determined by the current System Language.

To import the `CSV` file, you can use the [Encoding.GetEncoding()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding) method to specify the Name or `CodePage` of the Encoding used in the machine that generated the file: again, not the Encoding related to System Language, but the Encoding of the Language that the Excel Application is currently using.

[CodePage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (`Windows-1252`) and [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) are commonly used in Latin1 zone.
Based the symbols you're referring to, this is most probably the original encoding used.
In Windows, use the former. `ISO-8859-1` is still used, mostly in *old* Web Pages (or Web Pages created without care for the Encoding used).

As a note, `CodePage 1252` and `ISO-8859-1` are not exactly the same Encoding, there are *subtle* differences. 
If you find documentation that states the opposite, the documentation is wrong.